# secure params in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, security, parameters

I'm having a form that dont actually saving a model, so When i do POST the form, there is email and password, but somehow I dont want to expose my password to others.
I did this
config.filter_parameters to filter in the log

but when I POST and I check browser, there are still having plain text for my password which I dont want to. Is there any proper way to encrypt the params when sending that when I inspect in the browser, everyone will just see hashes or encrypted.

Oh ya,I meant the way not using SSL as well >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use SSL, then you can't be secure.

Even if you did private/public key encryption with JS before sending the passwords over the network, you can't trust that your encryption JS code wasn't compromised when being sent to the client. After all, you want to encrypt because you are worried about network vulnerabilities.

Of course, you could use JS encryption over an insecure protocol to give the *illusion* of security. To be fair, the attack to compromise the passwords in this scenario would need to be more sophisticated than simple network sniffing.

A great article on this topic is here: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: alright, should consider using SSL then, SSL can created by our own right? is that will actually apply to one url or all the routes path? will there a major changed if change to SSL ?

Comment: To use SSL does not require a change to the application, but it requires comfiguration of the web server (Apache/Nginx/etc). You can buy a certificate for an entire domain for around $30 (eg www.blah.com/*) or for all sudomains as well for around $150 (eg *.blah.com/*).  Once you buy the SSL certificate, follow the instructions from the certificate vendor to configure your system to use it. I personally get my SSL certificates from Comodo, and would recommend them as they have good help and support.

Comment: okay, because from this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/357-adding-ssl , i thought it can be setup free for the domain and subdomain as well.

Comment: There are some free ones. From the RailsCast: ````Once we have our Rails application working the way we want and we’re ready to deploy it it’s time to buy an SSL certificate signed by an authorized provider. Some providers can be rather expensive and this might scare you off but certificates can be found cheaply. A good place to look is your domain name provider as they often have partnership deals that let us buy certificates for good prices. For example DNSimple for as little as $20 a year. If this is still too much there are some free options available such as one at StartSSL.````